# Use $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {2n +1} {2^n} = 6 $ to show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {2n +1} {2^n} i^n = \frac 4 {25} + i \frac {22} {25}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've shown that the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {2n +1} {2^n}$$ converges to $6$ using elementary series operations.

However how can I use this to show that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {2n +1} {2^n} i^n = \frac 4 {25} + i \frac {22} {25}$$

and $$\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} (-1)^p\frac {4p +1} {4^p}$$ is convergent and has a sum which should be found ?

I don't see the connection, except that the second series is a product of a series I know is convervent (first series) and a series that is divergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$i^n=\begin{cases}\;\;\,i&,\;\;n=1\pmod4\\-1&,\;\;n=2\pmod4\\-i&,\;\;n=3\pmod4\\\;\;\,1&,\;\;n=0\pmod4\end{cases}$$

**Added on request:** Using the above and the sum of a geometric series with ratio $\;r\;,\;\;|r|<1\;$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2n+1}{2^n}i^n=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {i^nn}{2^n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac i2\right)^n=$$

$$=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4n+1}{2^{4n+1}}-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4n+2}{2^{4n+2}}-2i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4n+3}{2^{4n+3}}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4n}{2^{4n}}+\frac1{1-\frac i2}=$$

Now use that (yes, again geometric, but this time *power*, series):

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\implies\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}\;,\;\;|x|<1\;\;\;(**)$$

so for example

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4n+1}{2^n(=2\cdot2^{n-1})}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}+\frac1{1-\frac12}=2\frac1{\left(1-\frac12\right)^2}+2=10$$

$\color{red}{\text{But now I'm realizing there's a much easier way to do this...!}}$

Using (**) above:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2n+1}{2^n}i^n=i\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\left(\frac i2\right)^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac i2\right)^n=i\frac1{\left(1-\frac i2\right)^2}+\frac1{1-\frac i2}=$$

$$=\frac{4i}{3-4i}+\frac2{2-i}=\frac{-16+12i}{25}+\frac{20+10i}{25}=\frac4{25}+\frac{22}{25}i$$

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: It is explained there in the part with the asteriks, @user111854: it is the derivative of a power series converging for $\;|x|<1\;$ , so its derivative series *also* converges **at least** for $\;|x|<1\;$

Comment: Yes, but how do you know it converges to $1/(1-x)^2$. I'm aware the derivative has same convergence radius.

Comment: @user111854, **please** read again the asteriks part! We have a closed, easy form for that series and then we can differentiate termwise...etc.: $$\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)'=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: Ohh, you are taking the derivative of both sides considering the expression and series as a function of $x$. I'm sorry I didn't see that to start with, even thus I've studied the asterisk part. Thank you very much for your helpfulness.

Also, we did not use my first result at all in proving the second part ?

Comment: Nop, since going as the first part of my answer (i.e., with the powers of $\;i\;$), leads to sums modulo $\;4\;$ so I get expressions, for example,  of the form $$\frac{2(4n+1)+1}{2^{4n+1}}$$ which aren't easier to calculate (at least for me) using directly your result.

Comment: Just a little edit: after differentiation of the power series, shouldn't the index start at $n=1$ instead of $n=0$ ? (In the second last line in your answer).

Comment: @user111854, it doesn't matter that much as then $\;n=0\;$ and the whole first summand vanishes.

Comment: Thanks. I would have done it in your latter way. Was curious if it was possible to use the first series, but I don't think it is / don't see a way

Comment: Me neither, @CalvinLin. Once we try to use the powers of $\;i\;$ things like $\;4n\,,\,2^{4n}\;$ and etc. kick in, and then the OP's result isn't appliable...imo.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Hadamard formula shows the radius of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^n \frac{(2n+1)z^n}{2^n} $ is $2$. Techniques gives that series $=\frac{4+2z}{(z-2)^2}$ inside the disk(try it yourself! or at least verify it), and therefore if we take z=i the answer manifests. Sepereating the real part and the imaginary part gives the second answer.

Comment: What techniques have you used ? Just looking at $s_k$ ? (the sequence of sums?)

Comment: basically some techniques about power series(because i can swtich the order of differentiation/integration/limit and summing here!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{2n+1}{2^n}i^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\frac{4n+1}{4^n}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-i)^n\frac{2(2n+1)+1}{2^{2n+1}}}$

Comment: The problem is the two series are not well known to me. And how do I use my result ?